# Regular expression - match after specified pattern

Tags: regex

Is it possible to match everything after a certain pattern ?

```
starting-this is my string-
```

For example with the example above i know that the string will start with some letters and a hyphen and then the value i want which will be terminated by another hyphen.

So in the example i want to find "this is my string"

Is it possible to do this with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends. Every implementation of RegExp is different. For instance, you can't do it in JavaScript, but you can in Ruby. The feature you're looking for is called "positive lookbehind".

```
/(?<=starting-)this is my string(?=-)/
```

You have an example of both positive lookbehind and positive lookahead here: the former is a zero-width assertion that behind "this" you have "starting-", and the latter is a zero-width assertion that after "string" you have "-".

Most flavours of RegExp have lookahead. Some (like JS) don't have lookbehind.

If yours doesn't, there are some tricks you can do. The easiest one is to just make a non-lookbehind regexp, and capture the desired string:

```
/starting-(this is my string)-/
```

However, since the matches can't overlap, you might not be able to use this method sometimes. For example, if you try to match words surrounded by hashes, and try

```
/#(\w+)#/g
```

and try it on a string like "my #horse# likes to #eat#hay#for#breakfast#", you would only get "horse", "eat" and "for", since the matches for "#eat#" and "#for#" would consume the hashes around "hay" and "breakfast".

The other is to reverse both string and pattern, and use lookahead instead; but this is horrible to read, and also only works if you don't need both lookahead and lookbehind in the same pattern.

Comment: Man, you are wrong about JS. Consider `"starting-this is my string-".match(/^starting-([^-]*)-/)`.

Comment: @twil: I did consider it, and rejected it - you can read my updated answer for the reason. Specifically, try matching "horse", "eat", "hay", "for", "breakfast" from my example using your method.

Comment: Your answer is good but you are substituting one problem this another and stating wrong about asked question.

Comment: @twil: Which of my statements is wrong? "matching is not same as capturing"? "JavaScript does not have lookbehind"? "You might do this without lookbehind in some contexts, like the one asked in the question, but it doesn't work in others"?

Comment: "For instance, you can't do it in JavaScript"

Comment: @twil: Regarding the question's title, "match after the specified pattern", you can't do it in JavaScript. You *can* capture it by matching a larger substring. Why is the difference not getting through to you?

Comment: @twil: There is only one sentence in the question that might suggest your interpretation: "So in the example i want to find "this is my string"". All the rest is talking about "match". Programming is all about precision of expression; you might want to transfer that into natural language as well. In any case, you might have missed (even though I pointed it out) that your method works too *in this case*, and that I never suggested against it, just warned that there are circumstances where it doesn't work. And now that I've repeated myself more times than I care to, I'm out. Sapienti sat.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you told us the language you are using. For Perl, this would work:

```
/starting-([^-]+)-/
```

The string would be stored in $1. One-liner:

```
$ perl -le '"starting-this is my string-" =~ m/starting-([^-]+)-/; print $1;'
this is my string
```

Here is [an example in JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/RaffS/):

```
(function() {
    var str = 'starting-this is my string-';
    var matches = str.match(/starting-([^-]+)-/);
    alert(matches[1]);
})();
```

Comment: This matches more widely than "this is my string".

Comment: @Amadan, this matches what've been asked - some value between hyphens

Comment: This *captures* what has been asked. It *matches* more widely. See my answer for an example where the two are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use this:

```
(?<=textyouwanttomatchafter).*
```

This example would work in java, and should be similar in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one to capture the groups:

```
starting\-(.*?)\-
```

The match will be in the second group.

You can use that one to match:

```
(?<=starting-).*(?=-)
```

Comment: This matches more widely than "this is my string".

Comment: That uses groups to match.

Comment: It *matches* "starting-this is my string-". It *captures* "this is my string". There is a difference, which I was pointing out. If you simply want to extract a single value, it is usually sufficient; see my answer for a situation where it is not.